# new keyword with POJO returns null reference to nested objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, lombok

I have a POJO with lombok @Data annotation like this

```
@Data
public class RmsSearchRequestDto {
     private AuditCredentialsDto auditCredentialsDto;
     private RmsSearchCriteriaDto rmsSearchCriteriaDto;
}
```

the inner class are POJOs with @Data annotation again.

Now when I create a new instance of RmsSearchRequestDto as:

```
RmsSearchRequestDto rmsSearch=new RmsSearchRequestDto();
```

it sets auditCredetialsDto and rmsSearchCriteriaDto to null and results in NullPointerException when I try to access

```
rmsSearch.getRmsSearchCriteriaDto().getSearchType();
```

cause rmsSearch.getRmsSearchCriteriaDto() returns null instead of returning an instance of RmsSearchCriteriaDto (desired result)

This behavior is very strange to me and cannot find anything on google. I'm using Spring boot 2.5.6. This is a 20 year old legacy project and I did not have this issue until lately when I tried switch from CustomValidators to Spring Bean Validation. Thanks.

Comment: This is normal Java behavior.  Fields of a class are default initialized to `null`.

Comment: I can't access the Lombok site right now, but tutorials imply that with `@Data` you only get initialization code generated for fields if they are `final`.

Comment: Yeah I can't access lombok too. They seem to be down. Aren't they supposed to be initialized to the instances of the class though?

Comment: Not according to the examples in the tutorials I looked at.  (And it doesn't make a lot of sense to do that ... to me.)  I suspect the real cause of your problem is ... something else.  E.g. your changes have altered the way that Spring auto-wiring is working.

Comment: Thanks for comments guys. I misunderstood this default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Lombok site is down today but according to what I've heard from others. This is the default behavior of @data annotation as seen in the comments above as well. I changed this class from having only string fields to having nested classes which caused this confusion on my part. Refactoring my test cases to initialize inner class instances explicitly now. Thanks everyone.